# Does Palm/HP webOS 3.0 / Enyo framework support image maps?

Tags: webos, palm, touchpad, enyo

Does Palm/HP WebOS 3.o / Enyo framework support image maps??

I have an HtmlContent control that contains "image maps" -- an image with links embedded in hot spots using the HTML "usemap" attribute. However my those links don't seem to be active, and I cannot click on them. (The same page when opened in a regular browser allows me to click, but when that HTML content is in an HtmlContent control, the links seem to have disappeared).

Any ideas?

Also i did check that the click events are not being fired -- the click handler for the HtmlContent control does not fire. This does not happen when the entire image has an href -- in that case things work fine. But if the image has a map associated with it, then the links are not active, and clicking on the link regions does not seem to fire click events.

Answer (score 1):

It's not Enyo that needs to support imagemaps, but the lower level WebKit system.  Right now, webOS should handle rectangular image maps, but polygon maps weren't being handled correctly.

Comment: My image map was rectangular (i.e. <area shape="rect"...>), but no luck. Not sure if I understand your comment regarding the lower level WebKit system needing to support it, WebKit (say under Safari or Chrome) already supports it -- my image maps work fine under regular Chrome.

Comment: The image map handling is managed by the graphics layer which is below the WebKit level and implemented using custom code on webOS.